# How do I get the URL for the item using the Amazon API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

I'm making a ItemSearch request with keywords and the response groups 'EditorialReview' and 'Images', but I don't get back the DetailsPageURL, it's always null. I assume this would be the link (including my affliate tag) back to amazon. I've looked through all of the response groups, but I can't seem to find one which will offer this information!

Does anyone know how to get an affiliate link back to a product? Or do you have to build one yourself?

Thanks,

Andy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Url of each item can be found from the itemSearch request.

I got it from using item.ItemLinks as below:

```
string strLink = item.ItemLinks[0].URL;
```

If you look in the documentation:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/Associates/2011-08-01/prod-adv-api-gsg-2011-08-01.pdf

itemLinks is returned in the XML from the API

Comment: Hmm, seems pretty simple! I'll try it out when I have a couple of minutes! :)

Comment: Nah, ItemLinks is null for me. Is there a specific response group I need?

Comment: I use the response group Large and Small and I always bring back the URL for my item searchs

Comment: I'll try and check if using this response groups as well helps, may be a little while though, quite busy this week!

Comment: Still haven't had time to test this out but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's `DetailPageURL` – without an `s`. It's a direct child of the `Item` node. You wrote in your post that you're looking for `DetailsPageURL`.

As Standage said, it's the same URL as is found under `item.ItemLinks[0]`